# How to make jQuery wait after event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text boxes that uses AJAX and will process what the user types as they're typing. The problem is that the process that happens after they type is a pretty loaded one. Is there anyway that I can make the event wait 500 msec or so before it will process the event again? So let's say I type `a`, and then 200ms after I type `bsdke`. The event will only process `a` coming in. Let's say I then type `asdf` 600ms after I typed `a`. The event will then trigger and process `absdkeasdf` because it has been 500ms after the last process.

Or even, is there a way I can make the event not become triggered until the previous event that was triggered has finished what it was doing?

Is it possible? Surely sticking a timeout function at the end isn't going to work, right?

```
 $('#selection1-3-4-a, #selection1-3-4-b, #selection1-3-4-c, #selection1-3-4-d, #selection1-3-4-e, #selection1-3-4-f').on('input', function (e) {
    var url = "/ex.php";
    $.ajax ({
    //......

 });
```

Comment: yeah, it's called debouncing or throttling (depending on whether you want it to send the first request, and one every n ms, or if you want it to not send any until n ms have passed without input)

Comment: Is the entire typed string displayed on screen as it is typed or is the display delayed as well?

Answer (score 1):

It can get hard to tune the event so the users gets a nice experience and you don't flood the server with requests when using autocomplete functions.

I would do it this way:
The event will wait X miliseconds to run itself. If the event is fired again, and the X miliseconds haven't passed, you reset the delay to 0.

Let's be cool and make a generic function to do this (couldn't test it, it might be broken):

```
function delayedEvent(eventHandler, delay) {
    var lastTimeout = null;

    return function () {
        var that = this,
            args= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).sort();

        if (lastTimeout !== null)
            window.clearTimeout(lastTimeout);

        lastTimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
            eventHandler.apply(that, args);
        }, delay);
    };
}

$('... selector ...').on('event', delayedEvent(function () { ... your code ... }, 500));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout:

```
 var timer;
 $('#selection1-3-4-a, #selection1-3-4-b, #selection1-3-4-c, #selection1-3-4-d, #selection1-3-4-e, #selection1-3-4-f').on('input', function (e) {
    var url = "/ex.php";
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax ({
        //......
    }, 500);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a lock.

```
// global lock
var locked = false;
$('#selection1-3-4-a, #selection1-3-4-b, #selection1-3-4-c, #selection1-3-4-d, #selection1-3-4-e, #selection1-3-4-f').change(function (e) 
{
    if(!locked)
    {
        locked = true;
        $.ajax(......)  // ajax here

        setTimeout(function(){locked = false;}, 500);
    }

});
```

Comment: there's a slight problem with this... If the user types their whole query within 500ms, the only query that will happen would be for the first letter.

Comment: I thought that's what he wanted.  Maybe I misread it.--- I reread it... he wants to cache the var in the mean time.  I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: that does kinda seem like what he's explaining in  his question, but why would anyone want their input to perform that way? it's not going to search for what the user actually typed in.

Comment: I actually have run in to a similar issue in production.  You want to fire off a query but not overload the server by firing it too many times.

Comment: That would be a great usecase for throttling

Comment: Yeah, my lock is basically a poor man's throttle.  I normally do this with an unlock in oncomplete rather than on a timer.